# wpf datagrid angled header style

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, header, angle

I am creating the DataGrid angle header style based on [Margaret Parsons article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2010/01/06/angled-headers-in-the-datagrid.aspx).
Now it is looking like this:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderAngle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
          <Grid x:Name="HeaderGrid" ShowGridLines="True" 
              Width="30">
            <Rectangle Name="HeaderRect" Fill="Azure" Stroke="Black" 
                       Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                       Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
              <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <SkewTransform CenterX="0" AngleX="-60" AngleY="0"
                     CenterY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                              Path=ActualHeight }"/>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>

            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                   Background="Aqua"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                  <RotateTransform Angle="-30"/>
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                  <TranslateTransform  X="20"/>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>

            <!--ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Width="200"
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
              <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-30"/>
              </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
              <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform  X="18"/>
              </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
            </ContentPresenter-->

          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

`ContentPresenter` was changed to colored `TextBlock` for the purpose of seeing its borders.

My problem: by default Column width is equal to header text width so cell place usage is not optimal.
When I reduce column (`HeaderGrid`) width (by binding/converter or manually) the header text width is also decreased

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1WNd.jpg)

Is there any way to decrease column width without headers text cutting?

Answer (score 1):

I Know it's a long time ago, but I've used the same blog to implement my angled headers, and I thought i would post my solution to the cropping.
I found that it's the physical layout frame of the ContentPresenter that's limited by it's parent, so by using a negative number on the right margin, will expand the contentpresenter's layout frame so the text will be rendered.

**(NOTE: In my solution I used a TextBlock, not a ContentPresenter)**

I bound the the right margin of the Control to the inverse ActualWidth of itself to ensure the correct margin:

```
<TextBlock.Margin>
    <Binding ElementName="HeaderContent"
             Path="ActualWidth"
             Converter="{StaticResource MarginConverter}" />
</TextBlock.Margin>
```

With a converter:

```
<TextBlock.Resources>
    <converters:AngledHeadersMarginConverter x:Key="MarginConverter" />
</TextBlock.Resources>
```

Doing this:

```
class AngledHeadersMarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness(0, 0, -(double)value, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This seemed to solve the problem.